# How to limit size of output file from perl process?

Tags: perl, ant

I am calling perl process from ant and redirecting output to text file. I have to limit size of that file (it can fail the process completely or just cut the output). The file can get so huge that it will take any remaining disk space.

Relevant part of build.xml:

```
<exec dir="----" executable="perl" spawn="true">
       <env key="PERL_CAPTURE_OUTPUT" value="${logdir}/jboss.out"/>
       <arg value="runServer.pl"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using a unix like system, you could use `ulimit`.

And call your script like:

```
bash -c "ulimit -f <filesize> ; exec perl runServer.pl"
```

Alternatively you can keep track or written bytes from within your script and exit when certain limit is reached. Should not be hard to modify your script to do so.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: given the portability requirement, it would be best to keep track of what you write in your perl script. On every write, just sum the bytes and terminate when limit is reached. It will be more efficient and straightforward than writing another perl script and pipe through it. Moreover to pipe on windows you would need to call `cmd.exe` and on unix `sh` which is a complication on your ant task logic. @amon info is nice though.

Comment: I use the same script for Linux, Windows and Solaris, so it must work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you want (on a *nix system) is the `head` program. E.g.

```
some-command | head -c 1K >somefile
```

which prints the first Kb of data, then terminates. The program that is piping to `head` will receive a SIGPIPE – it may exit, or continue.

Now you want a platform independednt solution? We can do that with a tiny piece of Perl:

```
perl -pe'exit if $size > 1 * 2**10; $size += length $_'
```

which has the property that it will only cut off at the end of a line.

Test (cut off after first line end after 0.01KB = 10.24 bytes):

```
$ <<'END' perl -pe'exit if $size > 0.01 * 2**10; $size += length $_'
12345
78901
34567
END
12345
78901
$
```

Depending on the input, may get fewer output lines on Windows, because CRLF line endings have one extra byte.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it, my perl knowledge is very limited. I am calling a perl script from ant and perl script in itself does not write to file - it's ant where it gets forwarded to text file. Can I add this solution in my ant target, or do I have to modify perl script to save to a file and apply the limit there? It's just of the many perl scripts that I am calling this way, so I'd prefer to have a way to limit it from within ant.